# How to rotate with respect to a specific point in Asymptote?

Tags: asymptote

The page 47 of the Asymptote manual says that the `rotate` command "rotates by angle in degrees about z" as follows:

> transform rotate(real angle, pair z=(0,0));

I'd like to exploit this feature to arrange `n` circles around a hypothetical reference point such that each circle is a rotated version of its adjacent peer with respect to that point by `theta` degrees. The result would visually be something like:

[image]

Here is what I have tried.

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{asymptote}  

\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
    size(5cm);
    path p = circle((0,3),1);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
    {
        draw(
            p*rotate(
                (i*pi/18),(0,0)
                )
            );
    }
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

However, compilation yields: ***no matching function 'operator *(path, transform)'***.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to what I find it suffices to change the order. (I hope you do not mind me switching to `ayspictureB`, you only need to compile with `pdflatex -shell-escape`.)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{asypictureB}  

\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=robo}
    size(5cm);
    path p = circle((0,3),1);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
    {
        draw(
            rotate(
                (i*pi/18),(0,0)
                )*p
            );
    }
\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

In order to arrive at something reminiscent of your screen shot, supply units. (It *appears* to me that otherwise the units are taken to be pt, and the angle conventions seem to be as unfortunate as in Ti*k*Z, even though I thought this was not the case. At least if I use degrees, the result is consistent.)

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{asypictureB}  

\begin{document}
\begin{asypicture}{name=robo}
    size(5cm);
    path p = circle((0,3cm),1cm);
    for(int i=0; i<=10; ++i)
    {
        draw(
            rotate(
                (i*10),(0,0)
                )*p
            );
    }
\end{asypicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I do appreciate your help, sir.

Comment: @Roboticist My pleasure!

Answer (score 6):

You don't actually need asypictureB (or the more modern asymptote.sty package) or even the LaTeX commands if you run this example directly with asy.

The point of specifying size(5cm); is so you don't have to specify the units.
You can instead specify unitsize(1cm); if you are working in cm. Here is a
simplified version, rotating through 9 increments each of 10 degrees:

```
size(5cm);
path p=circle((0,3),1);
for(int i=0; i < 10; ++i)
  draw(rotate((i*10),(0,0))*p);
```

Comment: Nice to see here the coauthor of Asymptote!