# no matching function 'operator *(transform, void)'

Tags: asymptote

I need to rotate a label which is actually an imported image, here called `file.jpg`.

Given the definition of `rotate()` which is

```
transform rotate(real angle, pair z=(0,0));
```

and also the answer to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/513823/how-to-rotate-with-respect-to-a-specific-point-in-asymptote) that states the rotation has to be applied to an object from left, I tried the following minimal attempt

```
settings.tex="pdflatex";

pair center = (200, 100);
rotate(45, center)*label(graphic("file.jpg"), center);
```

Using a real image file, it throws the error

```
 no matching function 'operator *(transform, void)'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may note the difference between function `label()` and object `label` and how function `rotate()` relates to them. In particular, the signature of `label()` is

```
void label(Label L, triple position);
```

which means the object `graphic("file.jpg")` indeed acts like a `Label`. Since `rotate()` has to be applied to a `Label`, you should simply do

```
label(rotate(45, center)*graphic("file.jpg"), center);
```

Comment: I think that some more clarifications are needed. According to the manual,  graphic("file.jpg") is not a label but a string. Mayne that are equivalent in this case but we are in the dark because the label components are not documented anywhere.